# Querying a phone directory until end of input is reached

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, io

> I need to create a phone directory with given inputs, then I need to
>   query the dictionary for unknown number of given keys, if not found,
>   print Not found. Link of Original HackerRank Problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-dictionaries-and-maps)

I have written this code in Python3, and it's working fine. Please review, and suggest other ways of taking unknown number of inputs. Should it be done without using `sys`?

```
import sys
phone={}
n = int(input())
for _ in range(n):
    line = input().split()
    phone[line[0]] = line[1]
for line in sys.stdin:
    key=line.strip('\n')
    try:
        print(key+'='+phone[key])
    except KeyError:
            print('Not found')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care to adhere to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code formatting guidelines.  In particular, there should be a space before and after each `=` and `+`.  The `KeyError` handler should have just one level of indentation.

The phonebook could be constructed using a one-liner.  I consider it good practice to specify `maxsplit=1`, though it makes no practical difference when you are assured that the input will be well formed.

Getting the rest of the input using `for line in sys.stdin` is not a bad approach, I think.

```
import sys

n = int(input())
phonebook = dict(input().split(maxsplit=1) for _ in range(n))
for line in sys.stdin:
    key = line.strip('\n')
    try:
        print('{0}={1}'.format(key, phonebook[key]))
    except KeyError:
        print('Not found')
```